# Why is my vim colorscheme changing when I change buffers

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have some prefered colorscheme on some filetypes, but when I open another file (different file type with different colorscheme) and come back on a previous one, the new colorscheme persists.

I have this in my Gvimrc (using gvim)

```
autocmd WinEnter,FileType * colorscheme default
autocmd WinEnter,FileType c,cpp colorscheme darkblue
autocmd WinEnter,FileType R,r colorscheme desert
```

How can I modify to make sure that colorscheme persists according to filetype when I navigate across buffers ?

EDIT: adding the following did not fix

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufNew,FileType c,cpp colorscheme darkblue
autocmd BufEnter,BufNew,FileType R,r colorscheme desert
```

Comment: It seems you should add BufNew,BufEnter autocmds :>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not make sense to combine `WinEnter` and `FileType` events in the same autocmd rule; the first matches against the buffer's filename while the latter matches against the buffer's filetype.

Instead, use a single autocmd triggered whenever a buffer is entered / displayed in a window, and choose the colorschmeme with a conditional on the `&filetype`.

```
:autocmd BufEnter,FileType *
\   if &ft ==# 'c' || &ft ==# 'cpp' | colorscheme darkblue |
\   elseif &ft ==? 'r' | colorscheme desert |
\   else | colorscheme default |
\   endif
```

Comment: Works like a charm !!! thanks. Just to understand, why `#` and `?` for the filetypes ?

Comment: That's case-sensitive / -insensitive comparison to save some typing. You could also do regexp-matches with `=~`.

Comment: how do I amend this code to use `darkblue` for `.sql` files and `desert` for `.py` files and then `pyte` for everything else? ...just switch 'c' for 'sql' ? (or are c/cpp/r in this answer actual file extensions?)

Comment: @whytheq They are filetypes, not extensions. Check which one your buffer is via `:setl ft?`.

Comment: hmmm - thanks - initially thought romainl was the omnipresent vim poster but maybe you're taking over Ingo! p.s. not sure if you know much about db configuration via vim but I just added this question : [SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707574/can-vim-dbext-use-integrated-security-rather-than-a-sql-login-to-access-db)

Comment: @IngoKarkat is there a list of ft in the help. `:h ft` doesn't show one. Or say in your answer you use 'cpp' ...how do I find what that ft is?

Answer (score 7):

Ingo's answer is smarter but these autocommands

```
autocmd BufEnter *     colorscheme default
autocmd BufEnter *.php colorscheme desert
autocmd BufEnter *.py  colorscheme darkblue
```

should work. Well, they work, here.