# Can vim/dbext use integrated security rather than a sql-login to access db

Tags: sql-server, windows, vim, dbext

Currently I can access our db using `vim` with the standard `dbext` plugin.

I'm using the details of one of our a sql-server-logins to achieve this:

`type=SQLSVR:user=userName:psswd=userPwrd:dsnname=SQLOLEDB.1:srvname=boxname`

Could I change this connection string so that it uses my login credentials to get access to the server - in a similar way to `SSMS`? So that if vim is installed on this pc it will use the details of whoever logs in to this pc to access the db i.e. if a colleague with less access rights than me logs in to this pc then vim will use his details - his access to the data will thus be limited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@whytheq's answer works for "Integrated Windows Authentication", but if you want to connect using [Active Directory Integrated authentication](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48742), which is installed with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), you'll need to:

1. Make sure that the 32 bit version of `sqlcmd.exe` is on your search path by opening PowerShell and typing `get-command sqlcmd` and making sure that the source path starts with `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.  If if doesn't you need to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn` to your System's Path environment variable (before any paths which include the 64 bit `SQLSRV.exe`, of course).
2. Tell dbext to use `SQLSRV` instead of `OSQL` to execute queries by adding this to your `_vimrc` (ideally in an `augroup` as the [dbext readme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) suggests):

   ```
   let g:dbext_default_SQLSRV_bin = 'sqlcmd'
   let g:dbext_default_SQLSRV_cmd_options = '-b -G -N'
   ```

   Note that the `-G` tells `SQLSRV` to use the Active Directory Integrated Authentication, and the `-N` is for encrypting the connection.

---

**Aside**: Oddly, requesting a secure connection (`-N`) from a server that enforces a secure connection can result in an error message stating `SSL Provider: The target principal name is incorrect`, in which case you'll want to drop the `-N`

Answer (score 1):

This string works fine:

```
type=SQLSRV:integratedlogin=1:dsnname=SQLOLEDB.1:srvname=boxname
```