# Implementing more complex color scheme code for vim

Tags: vim

Currently I use a relatively simple snippet of code to dynamically change the buffer color scheme code in vim - [**detailed here on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692581/automatically-change-colorscheme-based-on-filetype)

[**This proposed solution**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme_to_show_where_you_are) looks a lot more comprehensive - I'm just unsure how to implement it.

```
if has('autocmd')
    " change colorscheme depending on current buffer
    " if desired, you may set a user-default colorscheme before this point,
    " otherwise we'll use the Vim default.
    " Variables used:
        " g:colors_name : current colorscheme at any moment
        " b:colors_name (if any): colorscheme to be used for the current buffer
        " s:colors_name : default colorscheme, to be used where b:colors_name hasn't been set
    if has('user_commands')
        " User commands defined:
            " ColorScheme <name>
                " set the colorscheme for the current buffer
            " ColorDefault <name>
                " change the default colorscheme
        command -nargs=1 -bar ColorScheme
            \ colorscheme <args>
            \ | let b:colors_name = g:colors_name
        command -nargs=1 -bar ColorDefault
            \ let s:colors_name = <q-args>
            \ | if !exists('b:colors_name')
                \ | colors <args>
            \ | endif
    endif
    if !exists('g:colors_name')
        let g:colors_name = 'default'
    endif
    let s:colors_name = g:colors_name
    au BufEnter *
        \ let s:new_colors = (exists('b:colors_name')?(b:colors_name):(s:colors_name))
        \ | if s:new_colors != g:colors_name
            \ | exe 'colors' s:new_colors
        \ | endif
endif
```

Which bits of the above do I need to uncomment?
Where do I add my default scheme pyte?
Where does it spot that if it is a fuletype sql then make the scheme SummerFruit256?
Or am I better just sticking with the simple two line code for switching colour scheme?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of changing the appearance of the whole program depending on the current filetype.

Comment: @romainl - do you leave the colour scheme alone?

Comment: I just use one colorscheme.

Comment: I quite like the idea of a couple of colour schemes - saves me getting too bored with one: just personal choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet defines a custom `:ColorScheme` command that sets a buffer-local scheme. You configure your own by invoking the command for your filetypes, e.g.:

```
:autocmd FileType sql ColorScheme SummerFruit256
```

or put the `ColorScheme SummerFruit256` command into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`.

You can set your default scheme via `:ColorDefault` or by setting it *before* the snippet as usual.

Comment: I'm trying to implement [your interim code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153381/why-is-my-vim-colorscheme-changing-when-i-change-buffers/15153602#15153602) (not as simple as my current two liner but not as complex as above) but this is failing? `:autocmd BufEnter,FileType *
\   if &ft ==# 'sql' colorscheme SummerFruit256 |
\   elseif &ft ==? 'python' | colorscheme IntelliJ' |
\   else | colorscheme pyte |
\   endif`

Comment: `Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "*": E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &`

Comment: Grr, that one got messed up. Again: The \ are line-continuation characters; they must appear at the beginning of new lines. If you want to put all on one line, remove the \.

Comment: ok - still getting an error message - I'll create a new question as this is more specific about the use of spaces and \ characters in vim scripts