# Use of spaces and \ characters in a conditional vim expression

Tags: vim

I tried to implement a version of Ingo's answer from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153602/1179880)

In my `_vimrc`file I have the following:

```
:autocmd BufEnter,FileType * if &ft ==# 'sql' colorscheme SummerFruit256 | elseif &ft ==? 'python' | colorscheme IntelliJ | else | colorscheme pyte | endif
```

I've taken the `\` characters out of Ingo's answer and tried to do it on one line but I still get an E15.

How are spaces treated in these vim scripts? and why doesn't this script work?

Comment: "and tried to do it on one line". ***Why?***

Comment: @Johnsyweb - "Why?" ...because it created an error with the `\` characters in it's multi-line form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ingo's Answer is copied below.

```
:autocmd BufEnter,FileType *
\   if &ft ==# 'c' || &ft ==# 'cpp' | colorscheme darkblue |
\   elseif &ft ==? 'r' | colorscheme desert |
\   else | colorscheme default |
\   endif
```

The `\` characters tell vim that the command should be on the same line as the previous one (if its at the beginning  of the line.) This allows long commands to be more readable.

Spaces are treated as separators between inputs to the commands so it doesn't matter how many there are.

In your command I believe you are missing a pipe `|` after the first if.

```
...   if &ft ==# 'sql' colorscheme SummerFruit256 |  ...
```

Should be

```
...   if &ft ==# 'sql' | colorscheme SummerFruit256 |  ...
```

So the whole command would be

```
:autocmd BufEnter,FileType * if &ft ==# 'sql' | colorscheme SummerFruit256 | elseif &ft ==? 'python' | colorscheme IntelliJ | else | colorscheme pyte | endif
```

Note: Since these commands are in your vimrc file, You don't need to the leading `:`

Comment: +1 good answer - now works - on one line or multi-line. The leading `:` is never needed before _any_ vimrc statements ? I still have it in front of some statements like this `:nnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>`. The only time I need to use the colon is when executing a command in vim ?

Comment: @whytheq you do not need the leading `:` to execute anything in the vimrc. However the colon is needed as part of the mapping. So you could just change the command to `nnoremap <C-S> :<C-U>update<CR>`